# MinMaxPriorityQueue using Java streams

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, guava, java-stream

I am looking for a memory-efficient way in Java to find top n elements from a huge collection. For instance, I have a word, a distance() method, and a collection of "all" words.
I have implemented a class Pair that implements compareTo() so that pairs are sorted by their values.

Using streams, my naive solution looks like this:

```
double distance(String word1, String word2){
  ...
}

Collection<String> words = ...;
String word = "...";

words.stream()
  .map(w -> new Pair<String, Double>(w, distance(word, w)))
  .sorted()
  .limit(n);
```

To my understanding, this will process and intermediately store each element in words so that it can be sorted before applying limit(). However, it is more memory-efficient to have a collection that stores n elements and whenever a new element is added, it removes the smallest element (according to the comparable object's natural order) and thus never grows larger than n (or n+1).

This is exactly what the Guava [MinMaxPriorityQueue](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html) does. Thus, my current best solution to the above problem is this:

```
Queue<Pair<String, Double>> neighbours = MinMaxPriorityQueue.maximumSize(n).create();
words.stream()
  .forEach(w -> neighbours.add(new Pair<String, Double>(w, distance(word, w)));
```

The sorting of the top n elements remains to be done after converting the queue to a stream or list, but this is not an issue since n is relatively small.

My question is: is there a way to do the same using streams?

Comment: This is not at all the point of `MinMaxPriorityQueue`: the only point of `MinMaxPriorityQueue` is when you actually need a double-ended priority queue to access both the greatest and the lowest elements, which does not seem to be the case here.  The `maximumSize` aspect is not the point of the data structure, and this will be seriously inefficient.  Guava's `Ordering.greatestOf` function is tightly optimized for this exact use case, and takes O(n) time instead of O(n log n).

Comment: (Future versions of Guava will have a version of `Ordering.greatestOf` specifically designed to match the Java 8 Collector API.)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I don't see a way though to use Ordering.greatestOf() without intermediately storing all elements in a collection first, is there any? Or will this only be possible in the future versions as you mentioned?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a collection, it can be an `Iterable` or `Iterator`.  If you have a stream, you could just do `Ordering.natural().greatestOf(stream.iterator(), k)`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, you said in future versions of guava. Is there any ticket you can link too so we track the progress? I guess I'm looking for something like `.stream().collect(myOrdering.greatestOfCollector(5))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A heap-based structure will of course be more efficient than sorting the entire huge list.  Luckily, streams library is perfectly happy to let you use specialized collections when necessary:

```
MinMaxPriorityQueue<Pair<String, Double>> topN = words.stream()
    .map(w -> new Pair<String, Double>(w, distance(word, w)))
    .collect(toCollection(
            () -> MinMaxPriorityQueue.maximumSize(n).create()
    ));
```

This is better than the `.forEach` solution because it's easy to parallelize and is more idiomatic java8.

Note that `() -> MinMaxPriorityQueue.maximumSize(n).create()` should be possible to be replaced with `MinMaxPriorityQueue.maximumSize(n)::create` but, for some reason, that won't compile under some conditions (see comments below).

Comment: Thank you very much @Misha, this seems to be the solution I was looking for. However, since your last edit in the code, it does not compile any longer:  `The type MinMaxPriorityQueue.Builder<Comparable> does not define create() that is applicable here`. It was fine in its previous shape though: `toCollection(() -> MinMaxPriorityQueue.maximumSize(n).create())`. What was your reason for the change?

Comment: @Carsten odd.  I just tried it and it compiled fine with jdk 1.8.0_25

Comment: @Carsten fewer parentheses make it slightly clearer (to my taste).  What version of jdk are you compiling this with?

Comment: I totally agree with you and I can't spot the cause of the problem, but it persists. I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_40. That is why I'm hesitating to accept your answer.

Comment: @Carsten very strange.  I'll poke at it in the morning.  In the meanwhile, I changed it back to lambda expression form.

Comment: Strange indeed. Anyway, your answer works perfectly for me, thanks agains!